# $e^-e^-\rightarrow e^-e^-$ scattering relative negative sign quick computation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section

In the QED scattering process $e^-e^-\rightarrow e^-e^-$ there are two possible diagrams in the tree level.

If I label the momenta I have, $$e^-(k_1)\quad e^-(k_2)\quad \longrightarrow \quad e^-(k_1^{'})\quad e^-(k_2^{'})$$

Now, when I write the matrix element/amplitude for these two seperate processes, I have,

$$iM_a=(\bar u(k_1^{'})(-ie\gamma_\mu)v(k_1))(iD^{\mu\nu}(k_a))(\bar u(k_2^{'})(-ie\gamma_\nu)v(k_2)) \tag1$$

$$iM_b=(\bar u(k_1^{'})(-ie\gamma_\mu)v(k_2))(iD^{\mu\nu}(k_b))(\bar u(k_2^{'})(-ie\gamma_\nu)v(k_1)) \tag2$$

where, $k_a=k_1^{'}-k_1=k_2^{'}-k_2$ and $k_b=k_1^{'}-k_2=k_2^{'}-k_1$.

The total amplitude for the process is given by, 
$$M=M_a-M_b \tag3$$

My question is, that for the second process I have a relative negative sign. Now its due to fermion exchange. I can write the matrix element out and see that the negative sign comes out naturally due to anticommutation amongst operators, as shown in Peskin(Chapter 4, Section 7).

**So how can I get this relative negative sign without expanding the operators? And also for any scattering process in general?**